# How fast will a shape grow if it can grow exponentially only at the border, and growth is limited by crowding?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

Take a hypothetical bacterium which divide once per minute. After $n$ minutes there will be $2^n$ bacteria, assuming no constraints.

But what if its growth is constrained by resources and space? I am imagining a simple model in which "food" is distributed uniformly across the plane/volume.

- There is enough food in the vicinity of any bacterium to divide *provided that it is not surrounded by other bacteria*. In which case it will divide and the space and food around it will be consumed.
- Otherwise there is enough food in the vicinity of any enclosed bacterium to keep it alive for as long as the experiment is running.
- Neither food nor bacteria can move.
- Assuming circular bacteria forming a honeycomb, imagine a "dent" in the border -- there will be four neighbours to the space and two gaps, *therefore only two of the neighbours will be able to divide*.

It's tempting to say that, although the central part is static, the *perimeter* will still grow exponentially and therefore the area/number will still be exponential, but I'd like an analysis which takes into account the crowding at the border. ideally for non-infinitesimal bacteria.

(I don't have a use for this, it just seems like an interesting exercise.)

Comment: Your discussion could take place in an alternative geometry where no crowding ever takes place: the geometry of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}$, where the perimeter of a circle of radius $r$ indeed grows exponentially as a function of $r$. But your assumption that the "isoperimetric ratio" area/number is exponential is incorrect for this example, indeed the isoperimetric ratio is actually bounded for large circles the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: This sounds like "a new border once per division cycle" which is one bacterium in size.  In other words, it sounds like growth matching the parameters of the shape (which I think eventually approximates a circle) and is thus quadratic for planar shapes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bacteria all multiply at the same rate then you are in effect adding "area" to the bacterial colony at a rate which is proportional to the perimeter. Say the colony has a radius $R$ then the perimeter is $2\pi R$ so the *rate* of bacteria growth is $\lambda 2\pi R$ for some $\lambda >0$. Thus we have a differential equation

$$\frac{dA}{dt} =  2\pi \lambda R = 2\lambda \sqrt{\pi\,A}$$

[According to Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dA%2Fdt+%3D+C+sqrt%28A%29) the solution to this is

$$ A = \frac{1}{4}(4 B\lambda\sqrt{\pi}\, t +C^2+4\lambda^2\pi\,t^2)$$

where $B$ and $C$ are constants. So you can see that the growth rate of the number of bacteria (which is $\propto A$) is *quadratic* in time not exponential.